# Is testing of one dal method with access to DB instead of mocks still the "unit test"?

Tags: unit-testing

I am a little confused with the definition of the term "unit-test".
If I write a test of a method without mocking the call to the database, and the downstream RPC. Do we still call this kind of testing a unittest, or this will become the integrated test?

From my opinion, the border is very blurred. From one side, only one function of this system is tested, and the testing is very "unit. From another, other systems are integrated into this one.

I provide one example for my question.

```
func InsertDiary(ctx context.Context, diary *model.DiaryDO) (string, error) {
    diary.ID = primitive.NewObjectID()
    coll := GetDiaryCollection()
    res, err := coll.InsertOne(ctx, diary)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    objID, ok := res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)
    if !ok {
        return "", err
    }
    return objID.Hex(), nil
}


func TestDiaryInsertAndGet(t *testing.T) {
    // insert one
    d := &model.DiaryDO{
        Weather:    "testWeather",
        POIName:    "shanghai",
        Feeling:    "good",
        Title:      "123",
        Content:    "123",
        SeriesCode: "0227",
        CreateAt:   time.Now().Unix(),
    }

    // delete one
    ID, err := InsertDiary(context.TODO(), d)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    t.Logf("Task-1: insert diary %s", ID)

    // get diary
    ctx := context.TODO()
    newDiary, err := GetDiaryByID(ctx, ID)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.NotNil(t, newDiary)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your test will fail other than changes in the function, then it is not testing a unit, (i.e) it is no more unit test. So, in this case if there is connection with database fails, then test will fail.

Unit test should run faster, so that you will get quicker feedback.  Unit tests are lot in number, if they start connecting to database, then it will take lot time, it defeats the purpose of unit test.

Integration tests do test these connections, so they are less in number and can take more time to run.